# Can't find vcvarsall.bat file

Tags: python, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to install Scrapy on my computer using pip. For the most part it works, but after a short while in the installation I get an error saying "unable to find vcvarsall.bat. I've looked around for help, and most sources say just to install Visual Express 2008. However, even after doing this, when I navigate to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC, I don't see the vcvarsall.bat file. Any ideas?

Comment: EDIT: Oct 11 2014. I didn't find a good answer to this when I asked three years ago, but accepted @silverfox's which vaguely helped. If someone finds an answer which can be corroborated, I'll accept, but I don't want to throw people off so I recently unaccepted that answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue7511) with disutils not finding vcvarsall.bat. It should be fixed in some release

There is a workaorund for compiling. Try this [blog](http://blog.victorjabur.com/2011/06/05/compiling-python-2-7-modules-on-windows-32-and-64-using-msvc-2008-express/)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**
We can install [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266) to solve this vcvarsall.bat problem.

First install lxml by [Windows Installer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml) from PyPI, it would save a lot from `libxml2` and `libxslt` include or lib issues.

Then install Scrapy by pip should be easy.

**ORIGINAL**
Microsoft Visual Studio 8 is VS2005.

Default directory of Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition should be C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\

Or you can just download the Scrapy installer for Python2.6.

[Scrapy-0.12.0.2542.win32-py2.6.exe](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12503247/Scrapy-0.12.0.2542.win32-py2.6.exe)

[Scrapy-0.12.0.2542.win-amd64-py2.6.exe](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12503247/Scrapy-0.12.0.2542.win-amd64-py2.6.exe)

Comment: I get `ImportError: No module named twisted.internet` after using installer.  I don't think the installer handles dependencies, unfortunately.

Comment: @CeasarBautista Could you write what information from the above answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm... it should be there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4d2c09s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

According to Microsoft, that is the "default" location, so it *could* be in another location.  How about a file system search below "Program Files (x86)"?

Comment: Just gave it a go. No luck. I'll try reinstalling. EDIT: Actually found it in Visual Studio 9 if that means anything, but nowhere else.