# Install flask-bcrypt via pip: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-2013, flask, pip, bcrypt

I try to install flask-bcrypt via pip, but it raisis me this error:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)
```

I am currently running `Visual Studio 2015 RC` with `Python 3` on `Windows 10`.

Any ideas how to solve this error?

**Edit:**
I tried to follow diffrent solutions and installed Visual Studio 2010 Express and am now stuck with teh following error (Installing via PIP in VS 2013):

```
Collecting py-bcrypt
Using cached py-bcrypt-0.4.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: py-bcrypt
Running setup.py install for py-bcrypt
Complete output from command "C:\Users\Niels\Documents\Visual Studio        2013\Projects\biospark\biospark\env_biospark\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Niels\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-3pqnujd2\\py-bcrypt\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Niels\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-syaty7au-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\Niels\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\biospark\biospark\env_biospark\include\site\python3.4\py-bcrypt":
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\bcrypt
copying bcrypt\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.4\bcrypt
running build_ext
building 'bcrypt._bcrypt' extension
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Niels\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3pqnujd2\py-bcrypt\setup.py", line 61, in <module>
    ext_modules = [bcrypt]
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\biospark\biospark\env_biospark\lib\site-packages\setuptools-15.1-py3.4.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 539, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 126, in run
    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\biospark\biospark\env_biospark\lib\site-packages\setuptools-15.1-py3.4.egg\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 50, in run
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\biospark\biospark\env_biospark\lib\site-packages\setuptools-15.1-py3.4.egg\setuptools\command\build_ext.py", line 183, in build_extension
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 503, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\biospark\biospark\env_biospark\lib\site-packages\setuptools-15.1-py3.4.egg\setuptools\msvc9_support.py", line 52, in query_vcvarsall
  File "C:\Users\Niels\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 287, in query_vcvarsall
    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
ValueError: ['path']

----------------------------------------
Command ""C:\Users\Niels\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\biospark\biospark\env_biospark\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Niels\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-3pqnujd2\\py-bcrypt\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Niels\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-syaty7au-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers "C:\Users\Niels\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\biospark\biospark\env_biospark\include\site\python3.4\py-bcrypt"" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Niels\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-3pqnujd2\py-bcrypt


'py-bcrypt' failed to install. Exit code: 1
```

**Edit 2:** I installed pycrypto via thsi Windows Installer: https://github.com/axper/python3-pycrypto-windows-installer which comes with bcrypt and suits my needs. But it would be nice to solve the original Problem.

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670365/python-pip-install-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-tried-all-solutions).

Comment: Following this thread i stumbled on a new problem, as stated in the Edit.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the problem can be solved by installing py-bcrypt first. A win32 installer is available from the first comment to this reddit post:

http://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/15q5xj/anyone_have_a_working_version_of_flaskbcrypt_for/

Comment: Now i get `py_bcrypt-0.4-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`. Pip is up to date.

Comment: Yeah the linked binaries are for Python 2; the question was about Python 3.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, you need to setup Wheel package before you can import bcrypt

```
pip install wheel
```

```
pip install bcrypt
```

```
 from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
```