# Attempting to install python-docx (error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-docx

I have tried everything and I have no idea where to go from here. When I call the command `pip install python-docx` I get this:

```
    running build_ext
building 'lxml.etree' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\alex\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Alex\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-u2i_l872\\lxml\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-26nq6ot7-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-u2i_l872\lxml
```

at the end.

I have tried locating vsvarsall.bat and setting the path. I can't seem to find it in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools and there is no tool folder in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7. I'm on 64bit Windows 10 and python 3.5.1.

Comment: If memory serves, vcvarsall.bat is in Visual C++ 2008.  Do you have that installed?

Comment: There is also this, if you haven't seen it already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670365/python-pip-install-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-tried-all-solutions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue people run into with Python modules. [You can read up more on it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat?rq=1)

What you can do is install a precompiled version of lxml, which is a module that python-docx relies upon. You can identify this requirement by looking at the error message, or by looking at the [python-docx github page here](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/blob/master/requirements.txt), which lists all requirements for python-docx.

Luckily, Christoph Golke provides some precompiled modules for us, [available here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml). <--- Hotlink that, you'll use it quite often.

Download and install the lxml module first from Christoph Golke, then try rerunning your pip install.

Comment: I attempted to install the first one and it said lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: NEVERMIND FIXED!! Thank you so much, got it to work! I chose the correct version for my version of python, installed lxml using this guide: http://www.apoorvakumar.tk/2015/06/30/installing-lxml-in-windows-for-python-3-4/ and then ran the pip install python-docx again. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

After countless tries to install the right Visual C++ compilers and setting the Variables, I got one step further but it still didn't compile. I suggest to follow the other answer's advice and install a precompiled version of lxml. After doing than, I could pip install python-docx without a problem.

Keep in mind that I had to use the WinPython Control Panel to install the downloaded .exe!

More information here: [Cannot install lxml on windows, fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libxml/xmlversion.h'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34536149/cannot-install-lxml-on-windows-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-li/38566861#38566861)