# python pip unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I am having trouble installing packages in python 3.5.1. I am running Windows 8.1 and After downloading Visual Studio 2015 for its compiler, I type, e.g.

```
pip install numpy
```

Into my command line, which generates the following:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.10.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: numpy
  Running setup.py install for numpy
    Complete output from command c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Yoni\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-hx_s0eag\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Yoni\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-bsqi93gl-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\yoni\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.5
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.5\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.5\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    Running from numpy source directory.
    C:\Users\Yoni\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hx_s0eag\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1651: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\Yoni\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hx_s0eag\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1660: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\Yoni\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hx_s0eag\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1663: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\Yoni\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hx_s0eag\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\Yoni\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hx_s0eag\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    C:\Users\Yoni\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-hx_s0eag\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    c:\users\yoni\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
```

Please Note that "numpy" is just an example packages: it does the same for "scipy" and all of the other basic packages that I have tried.

Further, I have tied a [number of solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670365/python-pip-install-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-tried-all-solutions) involving setting environment variables, e.g.:

```
SET VS90COMNTOOLS = %VS140COMNTOOLS%
```

With no effect.

I would like to be able to use PIP, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you check if there are any thing in the variable? Have you start the command window through vs tool in start menu?

Comment: @Boying- Yes, These changes are sticking in my environment variables (I have also entered them manually in the "Environment Variables" window, so I am not 100% sure that this is because of my command line effors). Specifically, I see the same directory location for VS90COMNTOOLS as I do for the pre-existing VS140COMNTOOLS variable.

Comment: For me, installing https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/python-vs.aspx makes everything work without any configs.