# pip - unable to find vcvarsall.bat

Tags: python, windows, visual-c++

From last week, I tried to solve this but couldn't fix this error. While, I tried to install, following error comes:

```
C:\Users\#######>pip install pyproj
Collecting pyproj
  Using cached pyproj-1.9.5.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    using bundled proj4..
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\H~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-e4o66o1z\pyproj\setup.py", line 72, in <module>
        objects = cc.compile(['nad2bin.c', 'src/pj_malloc.c'])
      File "C:\Users\######\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 317, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "C:\Users\########\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 210, in initialize
        vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
      File "C:\Users\#######\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 85, in _get_vc_env
        raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\H~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-e4o66o1z\pyproj\
```

I couldn't proceed ahead without fixing this error. I have installed Microsoft Visual C++.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pythonengineering/2016/04/11/unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2817869/253056 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/34602579/253056

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing some Python packages under Windows can be troublesome. You can find a precompiled package at

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyproj

Just download the `.whl` file that suits your Python version then install it using

```
pip install <filename>.whl
```