# Windows : cx_Oracle 5.3 install conflicts with Python (Anaconda)

Tags: oracle, python-3.x, anaconda, cx-oracle

I can't get to install cx_Oracle on my environment (64 bits Windows) :

- Through anaconda prompt : `pip install cx_Oracle` iget:

> Running setup.py install for cx-Oracle ... error  error: Microsoft
>   Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build
>   Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

- Through Anaconda Navigator, i get

> UnsatisfiableError:
>   The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
>   - cx_oracle -> python 2.7*
>   - python 3.6*
>   Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for each package.

I am running python 3.6 and pip 9.0.1, Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is installed...
**Why do i still have this python version conflict between 3.6 and 2.7?**

Thank you

Comment: When i do "conda info", i see that anaconda gets its cx_Oracle packages from https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64/, where the latest 5.3 version isn't available.
I tried downloading it and installing it manually but it is not working

Comment: That error message usually means the package is not available for Python 3.6. Try creating a Python 3.5 environment and installing it

Comment: I tried it but wasn't successfull, it seems like i need to change my environment variables as is explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670365/python-pip-install-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-tried-all-solutions , trying it right now

Comment: I meant, create a new environment and use conda (not pip) to install the package

Comment: Thank you, that finally did it. I created a python 3.4 environment and everything worked perfectly. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message usually means that the package is not available for Python 3.6 yet. You need to create a new conda environment to install the package into

```
conda create -n py35 python=3.5 cx_oracle
```

Comment: I had tried this, the package is ready for 3.6 since there is even an installer on https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Oracle/5.3 which i tried aswell. 
As you indicate, https://anaconda.org/ doesn't have the 5.3 package yet, but a manual install should have worked.
I'm still in the dark for the original conflict, but yes, downgrading Python seems to be the temporary answer

Comment: There is a difference between PyPI and anaconda.org. On Windows, it is very difficult to compile packages with pip, hence why conda is very useful. You may also find already compiled packages provided by Christoph here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#cx_oracle However, if you are planning to use conda, you should use conda to install all of the packages that you possibly can, so that there is no confusion within conda about what packages are installed (conda can't perform operations like install/uninstall on pip packages)