# Python 3.4 pyximport error

Tags: windows, pycharm, cython, python-3.4, importerror

I have two files named as experiment.py and low_dim_cython.pyx. I am using python 3.4 in PyCharm. In experiment.py, I tried to import low_dim_cython.pyx as:

```
import numpy
import pyximport

pyximport.install(pyximport.install(setup_args={'include_dirs':[numpy.get_include()]}))
import low_dim_cython
```

It throws these errors given below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 216, in load_module
    inplace=build_inplace, language_level=language_level)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyximport.py", line 192, in build_module
    reload_support=pyxargs.reload_support)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\site-packages\pyximport\pyxbuild.py", line 102, in pyx_to_dll
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 185, in run
    _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 339, in run
    self.build_extensions()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\site-packages\Cython\Distutils\old_build_ext.py", line 193, in build_extensions
    self.build_extension(ext)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 503, in build_extension
    depends=ext.depends)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 460, in compile
    self.initialize()
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 371, in initialize
    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
  File "C:\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\priview3.4\lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 259, in query_vcvarsall
    raise DistutilsPlatformError("Unable to find vcvarsall.bat")
distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pip install Error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat. Tried all solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27670365/python-pip-install-error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat-tried-all-solutions)